# Plot The Cornu Parametric Spiral

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

How do I plot the Cornu parametric spiral in 3D with *Mathematica*. The 2D is quite easy. For more details, you need to be familiar with the Cornu statement.

$$\begin{cases}
x(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\cos(u^{2})du&\\
y(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\sin(u^{2})du&
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 35):

```
body[t_] = Integrate[#[u^2], {u, 0, t}] & /@ {Cos, Sin}
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot3D[body[t]~Join~{t}, {t, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 BoxRatios -> 1, SphericalRegion -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I hope folks will help you get [Reversal badge](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/badges/57/reversal) :)