# Clothoid (using Fresnel Integrals)

Tags: plotting, special-functions

A clothoid is represented by 
[image: Clothoid]

---

### The Problem

Given the following functions, use Mathematica's Fresnel Integrals to plot the curve.
[image: Given Functions]

---

### My Attempt

```
ParametricPlot3D[{R (X[t_] := FresnelC[t], 
    Y[t_] := FresnelS[t])}, {t, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try `ParametricPlot[{FresnelC[t], FresnelS[t]}, {t, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]` instead.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45264) is related.

Comment: I was SOOO close!! Thanks Rahul!

Answer (score 3):

You are doing quite a few things wrong. It is really quite simple, though.

```
ParametricPlot[{FresnelC[t], FresnelS[t]}, {t, -3, 3}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image: plot]

Let's enumerate your errors.

1. Trying to promote an inherently 2D plot to a 3D plot.
2. Trying to define functions with `SetDelayed` inside a plot's first argument. Using `Set` would have worked, but making such definitions is entirely unnecessary.
3. Giving the unnecessary option `PlotRange -> All`

Comment: "Giving the unnecessary option `PlotRange -> All`" - it's not always unnecessary; in this case, we were lucky that the automatic `PlotRange` does not cut off Euler's spiral.